# How to sum values on each row with condition?

Tags: sql, if-statement

So, basically, I want to update my table by summing values on each row, but I don't want to sum negative values.

Here is some simple code that I've tried:

```
UPDATE recipe SET total_time = preparation_time + cooking_time;
```

But sometimes, preparation_time or cooking_time is equal to -1 and when it happens I won't to parse them to be equal to 0. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `case` expressions:

```
SET total_time = ((case when preparation_time > 0 then preparation_time else 0 end) +
                  (case when cooking_time > 0 then cooking_time else 0 end)
                 )
```

Comment: Thank you man, i didn't even know that was so simple